# AWS Kinesis video stream SDK for C not linking to my c++ program

Tags: c++, c, amazon-web-services, cmake, aws-sdk

I am trying to setup a peer to peer video call between 2 c++ programs and I want to use the aws kinesis video services with webrtc.

I am trying to use the AWS KVS SDK for C and use it with my c++ program
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-c

I am able to build the SDK but when I include it into my cpp main file I get a error

```
amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-c/src/include/com/amazonaws/kinesis/video/webrtcclient/Include.h:20:10: fatal error: 'com/amazonaws/kinesis/video/client/Include.h' file not found
#include <com/amazonaws/kinesis/video/client/Include.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Here are the steps I tool to set this up. I am a noob in c++ and c programming so I am not strong with cmake lists and builds but I have tried everything I could find

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-c.git

mkdir -p amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-c/build

cd amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-c/build

cmake ..

make
```

The build succeeded and then I tried to include the public include file in the c++ program using

```
extern "C" {
    #include "com/amazonaws/kinesis/video/webrtcclient/Include.h"
}
```

After this I used clang to compile and run

```
clang++ -std=c++17 main.cpp -o main `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4` -I/Users/…./…/sample/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-c/src/include -L/Users/…./…../sample/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-c/build -Wl,-rpath,/Users/…./…/sample/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-c/build -lkvsWebrtcClient -lkvsWebrtcSignalingClient
```

But then I got the error.
Here some additional things I tried.

I build using the build static libraries
I cleaned by deleting the build folder and tried to download the submodule directly and also cmake with dependencies

```
git submodule update --init --recursive

mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DBUILD_STATIC_LIBS=TRUE
make
```

still the same error where the other submodule include files are not building in the src directory.

I even tried to build each of the 2 projects manually but could not b uild the second one.

I need help to setup this sdk for c++ program

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be the uppercase -I for include, which is not included in system header searches.

> -I/Users/…./…/sample/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-c/src/include

Combined with a system header include.

> #include <com/amazonaws/kinesis/video/client/Include.h>

Changing to a lowercase i should work. Or changing the include to quotes.